# How to hide tab bar on Chrome/Edge on MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome

When I open Edge/Chrome on my MacBook and put it in Fullscreen mode, I expect it to show simply the contents of the page I am on. However, it also shows the Tab bar and Address bar. How can I hide this for screen sharing?